# Using Ajax in Laravel, returning 404 Not Found in console

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm trying to send a search query and display the results via ajax. For some reason when I submit the search I'm getting a 404 Not Found error message in console. Any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

***Update: just to clarify the URL is not foo/local/bar/... , I was just keeping that stuff private because I'm paranoid lol. Route was asked for, here is the only route involved:***

```
/*Home Page*/
    Route::get('/', array(
    'as'    => 'home',
    'uses'  => 'HomeController@home'
    ));
```

Here are the console error logs:

`POST http://foo/local/bar/public/ 404 (Not Found)`                     jquery.js:9597

```
Object 
   {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, 
   setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}              home.js:137

   error                                                                 home.js:138

   Not Found                                                             home.js:139
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //form_data
        var data = $('#search_form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                $("#search_results").html($search);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
                $("search_results").html("Failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function post_index() {
        $search_table   = Input::get('search_table');
        $search_column  = Input::get('search_column');
        $search_input   = Input::get('search_input');

        $search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
        echo json_encode($search);
        exit;
    }
```

View:

```
<form id="search_form" method="POST" action="" >    
    <select id="search_table" class="search_table">
        <option value = ''>Search</option>
        <option value = 'commissions'>Search commissions</option>
    </select>   

        <div class="search_box" id="search_column_div">
            <select id='search_column' name='search_column'>
                 <option value='select'>by ...</option>
                 <option value='street_address'>by street address</option>
                        </select>
        </div>

        <div id="search_input_div">
            <input id='search_input' name='search_input' class='search_input' placeholder='Enter Street Address'/>
        </div>

<input type="submit" class="button expand radius" id="search_button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see your `routes.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems with your code immediately. The firs it that your route is listening for a GET request but you're using a POST request in your AJAX call. The second issue is that you've named your controller function incorrectly. You're using the older Laravel 3 syntax but you've tagged Laravel 4 in the question. Using Laravel 4 RESTful controller function naming conventions, your function name should be postIndex()

Comment: I have to have the get request for that route for the home button to work properly, so I should form a different route with the same url and point it to HomeController@postIndex?

Comment: Made a route with a POST request: 
`/*Home Page Search*/
 Route::post('/', array(
 'as'  => 'search',
 'uses'  => 'HomeController@postIndex'
 ));`
and fixed the name on the Controller, now its public function postIndex() . Only now I'm gettin an "Internal Server Error " message.

Comment: Yeah, if you're defining each function route individually then you'll need to make a separate route to handle this function.

Comment: is it okay to use '/' as a route again since I'm using a POST request?

Comment: I had a 500 Internal server error, changed the url to 'search' (the name for the route that leads to the postIndex method in the Controller) and that fixed it. Now I'm getting a $search is not defined error. Baby steps.

Comment: You need to look at the Laravel documentation and make sure you're defining your routes correctly. Even if two routes have the same url, as long as the HTTP types are different, they won't conflict.